# Exponential of mixed-type End-valued differential form

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

Let $E\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ be a complex vector bundle and let $a_{(0,0)},a_{(1,0)},a_{(0,1)},a_{(1,1)}$ be differential forms 
 such that $a_{(i,j)}\in\Omega^{i,j}(\mathbb{P}^1,End(E))$. I would like to compute the degree (1,1) part of the form 
$$Tr(\exp(a_{(0,0)}+a_{(1,0)}+a_{(0,1)}+a_{(1,1)}))\in\Omega^{*,*}(\mathbb{P}^1,\mathbb{C})$$
Any idea please?

Comment: I am not clear how to define the exponential, because they don't commute.

Comment: @BenMcKay this is why it is harder to compute, but since you can multiply them the exponential is define